# How to specify custom children and parent property for tree layout in D3

Tags: d3.js

If I give the following JSON to d3, it works.

```
  {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "parent": "null",
      "children": [
        {
            "name": "Level 2: A",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "children": [
              {
                  "name": "Son of A",
                  "parent": "Level 2: A"
              },
              {
                  "name": "Daughter of A",
                  "parent": "Level 2: A"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 2: B",
            "parent": "Top Level"
        }
      ]
  }
```

But if I change to following it does not work. Note the changes are CAPITAL **C** in **c**hildren, **P** in **p**arent and instead of **name** I have **DeptCode**
So the question is is there a way to instruct d3 to work with a json with **C**hildren instead of **c**hildren, **P**arent instead of **p**arent and **DeptCode** instead of **name**?

```
  {
      "DeptCode": "Top Level",
      "Parent": "null",
      "Children": [
        {
            "DeptCode": "Level 2: A",
            "Parent": "Top Level",
            "Children": [
              {
                  "DeptCode": "Son of A",
                  "Parent": "Level 2: A"
              },
              {
                  "DeptCode": "Daughter of A",
                  "Parent": "Level 2: A"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "DeptCode": "Level 2: B",
            "Parent": "Top Level"
        }
      ]
  }
```

**EDIT:** I just found [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#children). But I could not decipher what to do. Can someone elaborate please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the given dataset

```
var treeData = [
  {
      "DeptCode": "Top Level",
      "Parent": "null",
      "Children": [
        {
            "DeptCode": "Level 2: A",
            "Parent": "Top Level",
            "Children": [
              {
                  "DeptCode": "Son of A",
                  "Parent": "Level 2: A"
              },
              {
                  "DeptCode": "Daughter of A",
                  "Parent": "Level 2: A"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "DeptCode": "Level 2: B",
            "Parent": "Top Level"
        }
      ]
  }
];
```

This is how you wire it:

Since the data has **Children** instead of default **children**.

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width])
    .children(function(d){return d.Children;});//this will provide children.
```

For text on the nodes do:

```
  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.DeptCode; })//the new label name
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

For collapsable node do:

```
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.Children) {
    d._children = d.Children;//since the children is stored in Children.
    d.Children = null;
  } else {
    d.Children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TTYoJfW6p8OuN0AJOu7Z?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, thank you. Its quite simple. By the way what does underscore in d._children represent?

Comment: when you click on a node the clicked nodes d.Children is moved to d._children and d.Children is made null. This is done so that the node does not show up expanded. vice versa when you click it again.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually much more simple than the accepted answer. All you need to do is let d3 format your data in the correct way (using `children` instead of `Children` and `parent` instead of `Parent`. In d3 v3 this is done with       d3.layout.hierarchy()` like so:

```
var myJSON = {
  "DeptCode": "Top Level",
  "Parent": "null",
  "Children": [
    {
        "DeptCode": "Level 2: A",
        "Parent": "Top Level",
        "Children": [
          {
              "DeptCode": "Son of A",
              "Parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
              "DeptCode": "Daughter of A",
              "Parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "DeptCode": "Level 2: B",
        "Parent": "Top Level"
    }
  ]
}
var hierarchy = d3.layout.hierarchy()
   .children(function(d) {
       return d.Children;
   });

hierarchy(myJSON);

// use myJSON like you normally would
```

This will add `children` and `parent` keys to the correct objects, and now d3 will be able to use your json without you having to make the extra changes suggested above.

EDIT:
Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uW7vmixjIQIWzrwEAcnm?p=preview)